# Binary Search Tree deletion of target node has two children

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

Here is my code, the replacement was correct (replaced the target node with the largest node in the left sub-tree), but after the replacement, both of the left and right sub-trees are gone.

Here is my code:

```
else if (temp->left != NULL && temp->right != NULL)
    {
        minLeaf = temp->left;
        minLeafMa = temp->left;
        parentRight = parent->right;

        while (minLeaf->right != NULL)
        {
            minLeafMa = minLeaf;
            minLeaf = minLeaf->right;
        }
        if (parent->left == temp)
        {
            parent->left = minLeaf;
            minLeafMa->right = NULL;
        }
        else if (parent->right == temp)
        {
            parent->right = minLeaf;
            minLeafMa->right = NULL;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You haven't asked a question. You only stated what you have and what it does!

Comment: Thank you! The question is that why both of the left and right sub-trees are gone after the deletion, only the replacement should have happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way of deleting a node `x` with 2 children is finding the inorder `successor` or `predecessor` of `x`, replacing `x`'s value with the `predecessor`'s or `successor`'s values and call delete on either of them(whichever you used).

You are using the `predecessor` here. You are doing

```
parent->left = minLeaf;
```

which points the left of parent to the leaf node(the `predecessor` node) resulting in all the nodes in between to be gone. Instead what you should do is

```
temp->data = minLeaf->data;
```

and recursively call delete on `minLeaf`.

Comment: OMG I was soooooooo stupid replacing the whole node. Thank you!